# jQuery - How to link together a DOM element and a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, object, inventory

I want to be able to link a javascript object with a dom element but cant find a way for this to be done properly. An example: say when opening a page with an inventory it loads all the items contained in it and when I hover over the images inside it creates a small tooltip with some information. Well there will be much of these items on the page and i want to be able to link the DOM element with an object so i can access its properties easily. I hope im explaining my self properly.

say I had this inside an inventory:

```
<div id="slot1"><img id="item1"></div>

<div id="slot2"><img id="item2"></div>
```

and say i have a javascript object called slot1 and slot2:

the object slot1 has all the properties that need to be shown in the tooltip so i would like to do something like this in the mouseover event:

```
this.showTooltip()
```

any help would be great ty if i need to explain it better just say!

-Thaiscorpion

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cluetip

Answer (score 4):

Use [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$("div.hasToolTip").hover(
   function() {
       //Get the associated data with the DOM element
       //with $(this).data(someKey)

       showToolTip($(this).data('toolTipInformation'));
   },
   function() {
       //Here you can hide all tooltips
   }
);
```

Obviously, before you can register this event, you have to assign the object to every DOM element with `$(selector).data(key, value)`.

These example expects that every DOM element which should have a tooltip has a class named `.hasToolTip`.

Look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for more information about the `.data()` function.

Comment: good ill take a look at that function its looks useful for this, ty!

Answer (score 0):

Just have the javascript object know the ID of the object it's watching.

```
function Tooltipper(divID) {
    this.id = divID;
}

Tooltipper.prototype.showTooltip = function () {
    // do tooltip stuff
    $('#' + this.id).tooltip(); // assuming that it has a tooltip thing
};

var slot1 = new Tooltipper('slot1'),
    slot2 = new Tooltipper('slot2');
```

And then:

`slot1.showTooltip();`

Or better yet, instead of passing in the ID, pass in the object:

`var slot1 = new Tooltipper($('#slot1'));`

This way you don't have to do a DOM lookup each time.